# Does every ROS node need to spin()?

Tags: ros, asyncspinner, spin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been using ROS for a short time now and learned about callbacks & spinning. My question is, since be default all callbacks are added to the global callback queue, does ros::spin() in node A also process callbacks for subscribers in node B?

For a specific example, in MAVROS there is a 4 thread asynchronous spinner. I built a ROS node that uses MAVROS. In my node I also use an asynchronous spinner to process callbacks; however if they both use the global callback queue then is my asynchronous spinner redundant?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237703/does-every-ros-node-need-to-spin()?/) by [powerstorm42](https://answers.ros.org/users/27240/powerstorm42/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2016-06-21**:
I can't comment on your specific use of MAVROS in your node, but in general, a spin in one node will not cause a callback to process in a different node. I know that from personal experience so have no cite for you. It's easy to check. Remove and see what happens.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2016-06-23**:
The term "global callback queue" means "global" within the context of the node process, not between different processes. You can either create an asynchronous spinner, call spin() or call spinOnce().

**Comment by [powerstorm42](https://answers.ros.org/users/27240/powerstorm42/) on 2016-06-23**:
Thanks everyone! I understand it know, especially Martin's explanation that the queue is only global within the node, not across all nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, every ROS node needs to spin, with the stipulation that your terminology matches conventional usage.

"ROS node" is conventionally used to refer to a *process* (or standalone executable, disregarding [nodelets](http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet)). (**Edit:** upon thinking about it, a more correct definition would also require use of a ROS callback queue. For instance, one might only access the [master API](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Master_API) in their executable; such a process would probably still be considered a ROS node, but it would have no need for a *spin*.) Threads, such as those used by an asynchronous spinner, are computational structures within a process. In the case of an asynchronous spinner, that are all able to use the global callback queue (thus, only one *spin* is necessary).

As to your use of MAVROS, it depends on what you mean by *I built a node that uses MAVROS*. If you run MAVROS as a node separate and distinct from your own node, then both need *spin* calls. If you've simply modified the MAVROS source, adding your own code to it that compiles into a single executable, then a single *spin* is sufficient.

Note that there are cases where it is helpful to use multiple *spin* calls (typically, multiple *spinOnce* calls with multiple threads) within a single node, and it is also sometimes useful to set up multiple callback queues within a single node. But these are beyond your question; any (communicating, functioning) ROS node must have at least one callback queue and one *spin* call.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2016-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1